# ReSharper, <inheritdoc /> and hover Intellisense

Tags: resharper, intellisense

Is ReSharper supposed to provider pop-up intellisense documentation for items that use the  tag when you hover over a usage of that item?

If so, it's not working for me - at least, not consistently. Using ReSharper Ultimate 2018.1.3

```
public interface IFoo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value of Bar
    /// </summary>
    int Bar { get; set; }
}

public class FooImpl : IFoo
{
    #region Implementation of IFoo

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class TestFooImpl
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var foo1 = new FooImpl
        {
            Bar = 3
        };
    }
}
```

When I hover over a reference to FooImpl.Bar, I don't get any useful pop-up Intellisense:
[image]

But when I do ctrl+shift+F1:

[image]

ReSharper is configured to override the usual VS intellisense behavior:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Enhanced Tooltip plugin (https://github.com/MrJul/ReSharper.EnhancedTooltip/ or via R# Extension manager)? It works for me, but I'm not sure if it's the plugin or some R# setting.